# Python Scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

The code below returns the "H" value for the span variable but I am looking for it to return the dollar amount 23988.00. Edited HTML for more scope

```
search_highprice=[]
result_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="tile_high-label"]')

for element in result_elements:
search_result = element.text
search_highprice.append(search_result)
```

```html
<div class="tile_high-low pull-left" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67);">
  <div>
      <span class="tile_high-label">H</span> 
        23988.00
  </div>
   <div>
      <span class="tile_low-label">L</span> 
      23535.00
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the value you want is not inside the `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar amount is contained within the div.so you have to target the element.

```
search_highprice=[]
result_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="tile_high-label"]/..')

for element in result_elements:
            search_result = element.text
            search_highprice.append(search_result)
```

## you may need to trim the extra spaces from text before appending.

Comment: Wow. Your answer is spot on! Thank you I could not find that anywhere. Thank you I add a replace so my final answer is

Comment: search_result = element.text.replace('H','')